# the extjs effection(slidein slideout)

Tags: animation, extjs, element

Hi:
From the api I found extjs provide some basic animation,for exmaple the fadeIn fadeOut and etc.
However when I use them, I meet some problems.

I am confusing about the component of its show and hidden.

The animation is called to the Element,for exapmle,

```
form.getEl.fadeIn(...);
```

But for a component,it has a attribute of **hidden**,

And for a html element,it has a attribute of display,and visibility.

So what does the extjs use when we fadeOut/slideOut a Ext.Element?
Also what does the extjs use when hidden a Ext.Component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, components are not ready to support animations. But this depends mostly on the layout of the container of this component.

For exemple, the border layout use a kind of "slideIn/Out" for its "collapsable" components.

You can try any animation on the component's `getEl()`, but it can have unpredictable effects, depending on the layout.

Comment: I know this. The animation occurs only on the Element(the Dom) layer,however I want to know when we call a ext.element to slidein/slideout, what does ext do to the related dom element in the html?